# Get Type of assembly by file name without using reflection

Tags: c#, localization

Here is my code

```
ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager("App_LocalResources",typeOf(MyResource));
```

This works fine, but I want to create ResourceManager by physical file name or by it's path.
How is it possible in c# ?

Comment: You mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.createfilebasedresourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: I tried to use this but , i don't have a Type to send here for the function. Type usingResourceSet

Comment: use null for the usingResourceset *if null, the default runtime ResourceSet object is used.*

Comment: Yes, i tried null too. But it then returns empty resource set

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution here! I needed to convert .resx file into .resource file.
For example :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>resgen E:\MyResource.resx E:\MyResource.resources
```

This worked!